# Installed printer will not print

Tags: 15.04

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04.  Tried installing my printer, HP Officejet Pro 8600.  Everything appears to be ok, but all print jobs are held.  Checked cups conf, and it appears to be correct. In the printer settings, the printer appears to be set as default, as set as default is grayed out and cannot be chosen.  There is a green check mark on the printer.  Can anyone advise??

Comment: I can't check this at the moment, but a printer can be paused.

Comment: And check the error log in `/var/log/cups`

Comment: I am totally lost with Ubuntu, can you tell me, when you can 1) how to check and see if printer is paused, and 2) how to check the error log.

Answer (score 2):

I went into printer properties and made a few changes and now the printer is working. I changed the Device URI, and the make and model, and the test page printed.  Went into my documents and printed off several docs.  Appears to be ok now.  Thanks for your assistance!